# Executing functions from a function reference/alias in f#

Tags: function, reference, f#

I am still very new to F# and functional programming so take that into account...

I want to write a communication handler that reads data from a CAN bus and executes a different function (or the same function with different behaviour) based on the ID. I know I can just write a function like a C switch statement (I.E. Match with...) but I would like the handler to be more generic (data driven) so I can reuse it.

I thought I would pass in a Map (or some other useful data structure) when creating the handler. I am also trying to do this with all immutable types if I can (not my normal way of thinking).

I wrote some simple test code that won't compile and after trying different ways and lots of web searching, I am still not able to figure it out. Which makes me wonder if I am going about this in the completely wrong way.

Simple test code:

```
let one() = printfn "One"
let two() = printfn "Two"

let callbacks =
    [ ( 1, one );
      ( 2, two )
    |> Map.ofList

let f = callbacks.TryFind(1)
f()
```

It doesn't like f(). Says it is not a function. If I rewrite

```
let f() = callbacks.TryFind(1)
```

It still does not like it.

How would I call f()? Am I going about trying to solve me problem in the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member `TryFind` as well as `Map.tryFind` function return an `Option<V>`:

```
let f = callbacks.TryFind(1);;

val f : (unit -> unit) option = Some <fun:callbacks@4>
```

That means you can't just call the function, you have to handle the situation when the key was not found in the map and *there is no matching value*. It can be done via pattern matching:

```
let r = match f with
        | Some(fn) -> fn()
        | None -> // what now? You can just return unit
                  ()
```

or via combinators to the same effect:

```
callbacks |> Map.tryFind(1) |> Option.iter(fun f -> f());;
One
val it : unit = ()
```

You might notice that nothing happens if the key is not found in this case:

```
callbacks |> Map.tryFind(5) |> Option.iter(fun f -> f());;
val it : unit = ()
```

The behavior is all documented in the [`Core.Option` module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370544.aspx), [here's `iter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340387.aspx)